# Dictionary and Items protected members of a KeyedCollection in Unity3d 5.3.1?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

I've been using Unity 5 for a year and everything worked fine until last week when we had the idea to update our IDE to 5.3.1 version.

Now the compiler shows two errors:

```
The name `Dictionary' does not exist in the current context.
The name `Items' does not exist in the current context.
```

both localized in a simple KeyedCollection

```
public class CommandProcessQueueCollection : KeyedCollection<int, CommandProcessQueue>
{
   public bool TryGetQueue(int id, out CommandProcessQueue queue)
   {
       if (Dictionary != null)
       {
           return Dictionary.TryGetValue(id, out queue);
       }

       foreach (var i in Items)
       {
           var k = GetKeyForItem(i);
           if (Comparer.Equals(id, k))
           {
              queue = i;
              return true;
           }
       }
       queue = default(CommandProcessQueue);

       return false;
   }

   protected override int GetKeyForItem(CommandProcessQueue queue)
   {
      return queue.Id;
   }
}
```

After several attempts things became even more tricky as the exact same code has been compiled in 5 different machines with 5.3.1 installed.

Well, 2 out of 5 proved to compile **without any error**.

Furthermore, msbuild seems to compile the code without any error as well.

Probably, there are differences, among the machines, in the .NetFramework used by Mono for compilations.

Do you have any idea about this odd issue?

PS: I'm adding `using System.Collections.ObjectModel` and my current API compatibility option in Unity editor is set to .NET 2.0.

Comment: FWIW did you try replacing, in the code, `Dictionary` with `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Dictionary` explicitly?  (Even thought you `using`.)  Could be a woe caused by a conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my team solved.

In those machines Windows Support for Editor 5.3.1f1 was not installed therefore the standard module of webplayer was running and few API of .NET were not available.